# Can't center <li>

Tags: html, css, sass

The footer section where I'm having trouble centering `<li>` elements: https://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/VWgxBY

```
footer {
  background: $footer-blue;
  border-top: 1px solid #4C68B9;
  text-align: center;

  a {
    color: $white;
    transition: color 0.3s;

    &:hover {
      color: $teal;
    }
  }

  .social-links li {
    float: left;
    font-size: $smaller-heading-size;
    padding: 40px 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs That's because it's sass - I'll add tag

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ah dankes :) for someone like me, I was like hm, that's wrong hahaha :) will remove my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace...

```
footer .social-links li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 40px 20px; }
```

... with...

```
footer .social-links li {
  display : inline-block; 
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 40px 20px; }
```

That should do it!

Adding the `display : inline-block` allows you to correctly center in case the width of your browser is large.

Removing the `float: left` allows you to correctly center in case the width of your browser is small.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm once again facing a similar issue. I'm doing the responsiveness part for the header, and there, after the width of the screen reaches  1061px or lower, I want for the `<li>` elements inside `<nav>` to spread out and be centered, just like in the footer, but nothing helps, also, for some reason, some names, that are made up from two words inside those `<li>` elements break. https://codepen.io/Kestvir/full/VWgxBY/

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with a corresponding demo and link to your new question from these comments. The demo will make it easier for me (or anyone else) to reproduce & debug your problem and the new question will make it easier for you to get someone else to help you in case I don't have the time to help you or I can't find a way to fix your problem. ;-)